# Active directory - Get computer IP by user SID

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I retrieve with C# a computer IP were a user logged using active directory?

Comment: Active Directory doesn't store such information - it's a *static* repository of users, computers, groups etc - but it does **not** store "dynamic" data about who is logged in from where.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to query the Security Event Log on any domain controllers that may have authenticated the user.  The logon event will contain the name (and I think the IP) of the workstation used to logon.

Comment: THe problem with this (and this is the only way, do not get me wrong) is that a lot more than a logon may possibly trigger this. In many setups user enter passwords for their domain account in a lot more occasions and all those security events also show up.